# Why is connecting to MongoDB Atlas with JVM Google Cloud Functions so slow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

I've been using GCF with Node/Typescript/MongoDB Atlas for a while and it all works pretty seamlessly with cold starts (and connecting to Atlas) only lasting a few seconds. Recently I started playing around with the same functionality using the JVM runtime with Kotlin. I've found that when I test locally, during cold start the connection time to Atlas is comparable with the Node environment, but when connecting from GC, during cold start it can take up to 10 seconds to make a connection! I've created my Atlas cluster on GC and I've used a region in the US. I'm wondering if there isn't anything I'm missing to speed up the connection time? Below is the implementation I've been testing with.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.1'

    // MongoDB & KMongo
    implementation "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.1.1"
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.1.1'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.7'
    implementation 'org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:bson:4.1.1'

    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.30"
}
```

Connecting to MongoDB Atlas:

```
object Database {

    init {
        System.setProperty(
            "org.litote.mongo.test.mapping.service",
            "org.litote.kmongo.jackson.JacksonClassMappingTypeService"
        )
    }

    private val uri = MongoClientURI(MONGO_CLIENT_URI)

    private val mongoClient = KMongo.createClient(uri.uri)

    val database = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.database).coroutine
}
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What is slow? The startup? The connection? The bitrate?

Comment: Could you share more details of your implementation so that we could check possible issues?

Comment: @RafaelLemos I've edited my initial post to include my implementation for connecting to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: I would say that your implementation is correct, are you using the same region for both functions

Comment: @RafaelLemos yes, both the GC project and the MongoDB Atlas cluster are both using the us-central1 region.

Comment: In that case I think the only way you will find out what is causing this delay is with someone inspecting your project and it's configuration, I would suggest that you seek [Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) for that.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help @RafaelLemos, I'll take your advice and give that a try.